# Map search results show in a table

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, mapkit, xcode6

I am working on a school project and I can't figure out how to have someone search for a location and then have the  results show in a table view.

Ive searched everywhere for some way to do this but found nothing.

Comment: in what form are the search results?

Comment: Forgive me for a stupid response/question but I am new to swift and cant reach my instructor but what do you mean by form. I know right now I have a UIText and button and they put in what they are looking for and then it searches nearby but instead of segue into a mapview with annotations it shows up in a table view.

Comment: Is the search entered in a search box?  Do the answers come back as map points or text locations or how?

Comment: It means, how are you searching? - Are you calling some web service and getting JSON back?  Are you using MKLocalSearchRequest?

Comment: I haven't started with either method yet I was told to do one or the other and I have not idea which would be best. God bless you guys for putting up with me with this. What would be the best approach. Basically I have to make a similar app like this: http://www.foodanddrinkguides.co.uk/iphone/index.html#screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (with the Apple's API, at least) two types of searches:

- [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html) lets you search for an address, or do a reverse search on the basis of the coordinates (e.g. to get the address of the selected coordinates). For example:

  - If you want to search for an address within a region use [`geocodeAddressString(_:in:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423591-geocodeaddressstring) (passing it the map's region);
  - If you want to search the world for a given address string, use [`geocodeAddressString(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423509-geocodeaddressstring);
  - If you want to perform reverse geocode lookup of a particular coordinate, use [`reverseGeocodeLocation(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation).
- [`MKLocalSearch`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/index.html) lets you search within a particular `MKRegion` (e.g. the visible portion of the current map) for points of interest. To do that, you:

  - Create a [`MKLocalSearch.Request`](http://MKLocalSearch.Request), setting its `region` (presumably to your map’s `region`) and `naturalLanguageQuery`; and
  - And then instantiate a `MKLocalSearch` and then start the search with [`start(completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch/1452652-start).
- If your goal is to show completions for an address as a user types it, you can use [`MKLocalSearchCompleter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter).

I assume you're looking for the `MKLocalSearch`, but these are the basic kinds of searches you can do.